# Spark Kafka Batch write with SASL mechanism throwing Timeout Exception with topic not present in metadata

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timeoutexception, spark-kafka-integration

I am reading data from cassandra db and applying few transformations on it and sending the data to kafka via .save() batch method. I am also using Kafka Producer to set the properties. But everytime i am getting the below error :
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic XXXXXXXXXXXXX not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
All configurations, credentials are set.
Same code is working fine on local as there is no SASL mechanism present there, but on cluster getting the above exception.
Please help.

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/apps/xxxx/jaas.conf")
val props = new Properties()
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("acks","all")   
props.put("bootstrap.servers","xxxxxx1:9095,xxxxxx2:9095,xxxxx3:9095")
props.put("ssl.truststore.location","/home/xxxxx/ocrptrust.jks")
props.put("ssl.truststore.password","xxxxxxxxx")
props.put("sasl.mechanism","SCRAM-SHA-512")
  props.put("sasl.jaas.config","org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"password\";")
props.put("security.protocol","SASL_SSL")
val producerConfig = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)
jsonRead.selectExpr("CAST(householdID AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
.write.format("kafka")
.option("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
.option("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
.option("acks","all")
.option("ssl.truststore.location","/home/xxxxx/ocrptrust.jks")
.option("ssl.truststore.password","xxxxxx")
.option("sasl.mechanism","SCRAM-SHA-512")
.option("sasl.jaas.config","org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"password\";")
.option("security.protocol","SASL_SSL")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","xxxxxx1:9095,xxxxxx2:9095,xxxxx3:9095")
.option("topic", "xxxxxxxxxxx").save()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cluster"?, where is your Kafka deployed?

Comment: post producer config you are using, that will help to answer your question

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 Kafka enterprise is deployed on Azure